# New Checkout Billing Address Form Field not saving value to the database

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, requirejs, customer-address, billing-address

I have added a new checkout billing address form field for entry of an optional field for the customer.

Have overridden the template checkout form and able to get the field onto the form, but cannot do anything with the data that is inputted into it, when a user enters data nothing is done with it.

[image]

Custom Field is the field that is added, I need what is entered into the text field to be saved into the Customers Billing address

[image]

And then it should appear along with the rest of the billing information

Comment: what error you have getting?

Comment: there is no error, it just doesn't save the data that is inputted into the custom field

Comment: Fixed. Couple of admin changes.

Comment: What changes did you make?